# Hilbert style proof for $ \left( \left( A\rightarrow \left( A\wedge \neg A\right) \right) \rightarrow \left( A\rightarrow A \right) \right) $

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

How can I proof that the following formula is a tautology by using Hilbert calculus?
$ \left( \left( A\rightarrow \left( A\wedge \neg A\right) \right) \rightarrow 
      \left( A\rightarrow A \right) \right) $

I know that I have to define axioms and apply the *modus ponens*. So I studied the examples in [this document](http://www.qedeq.org/current/doc/math/qedeq_formal_logic_v1_de.pdf), however I do not know how to apply this method on my particular formula.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: It is necessary to say exactly which Hilbert system you mean. For all we know, every tautology is already an axiom of your Hilbert system, and then the formula has a one-line proof.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually I do not have any additional information about the Hilbert system I am supposed to use. So maybe this one-line proof is sufficient for my submission :-)

Comment: I doubt it, somehow. But the answer really does depend on the choice of axioms - there are many Hilbert-style systems with different, but equivalent, sets of axioms.

Comment: With Ax.1 and Ax.2 you can easily prove $A \to A$. Then use it and *modus ponens* with a suitable instance of Ax.1: $A \to (B \to A)$.

Comment: See the answr to this [post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1069497/prove-lnot-c-implies-lnot-b-implies-b-implies-c-without-the-deductio) for the derivation of $A \to A$.

Comment: Thank you both! I understand it now.

Comment: @CarlMummert {CpCqp, CCpCqrCCpqCpr} under hypothetical syllogism and uniform substitution is not equivalent to {CpCqp, CCpqCCpCqrCpr} under substitution and detachment, even though both sets are equivalent under condensed detachment.  {CCCpqrCCrpCsp} under substitution and detachment is not equivalent to {CpCqp, CCpCqrCCpqCpr, CCCpqpp} under antecedent commutation and substitution [that is the rule C$\alpha$C$\beta$$\gamma$ $\vdash$ C$\beta$C$\alpha$$\gamma$], but again the axiom sets under condensed detachment are equivalent.

Comment: @CarlMummert Oh... also {CCCpqrCCrpCsp} under antecedent commutation and substitution is not equivalent to {CCCpqrCCrpCsp} under substitution and detachment.  Many more examples exist like that.

Comment: @Doug Spoonwood:  Thanks for the examples, but I am a little slow this morning - could you let me know what they are showing? Since you pinged me I think it must be something I wrote, but I can't remember the relationship.

Comment: @CarlMummert I responded to you saying "But the answer really does depend on the choice of axioms - there are many Hilbert-style systems with different, but equivalent, sets of axioms."  It's the sets of axioms and the sets of rules together which are equivalent or not equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that axiom 1 allows you to get a conditional which has any antecedent you want so long as the consequent is a theorem.  For this reason, we can call axiom 1 'recursive variable prefixing.'  Axiom 2 we can call 'self-distribution'.

Thus, use recursive variable prefixing and self-distribution to deduce (A→A).  Use recursive variable prefixing and (A→A) to deduce (B→(A→A)).  Lastly, apply a substitution to obtain your formula.