# theorem of formalized calculus $⊢ (F→ ¬F)→ ¬F$

Tags: logic

How can I prove that $⊢ (F→ ¬F)→ ¬F$

If it is known that

$(A1):F→(G→F);$

$():(F→(G→H))→((F→G)→(F→H));$

$():(¬G→¬F)→((¬G→F)→G).$

Comment: I assume your only rule of inference is Modus Ponens?  Can you use the Deduction Theorem? What did you try?

Comment: it is possible to use a deduction theorem

Comment: I have tried to prove it same way as F -> F

Comment: Well, it's going to be a good bit more complicated than $F \rightarrow F$ ... but the Deduction Theorem will be a life saver! .... OK, start with trying to prove $\neg \neg F \vdash \neg F \rightarrow G$

Comment: what will it give if I don't have G?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Hint*

We need some prliminary results:

A) $\vdash \lnot \lnot F \to F$

B) $\vdash F \to F$

C) $A \to B, B \to C \vdash A \to C$.

---

Now for the proof:

1) $F \to \lnot F \vdash \lnot \lnot F \to \lnot F$ --- using A) and C) above

2) $\vdash (¬¬F → ¬F) → ((¬¬ F → F) → ¬F)$ --- axiom (A3)

3) $F \to \lnot F \vdash (¬¬ F → F) → ¬F$ --- from 1) and 2) by *MP*

4) $F \to \lnot F \vdash ¬F$ --- from A) and 3) by *MP*

> 5) $\vdash (F \to \lnot F) \to ¬F$ --- from 4) by *DT*.

---

*Note*: for the proof of some of the results above, you can see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1069497/prove-lnot-c-implies-lnot-b-implies-b-implies-c-without-the-deductio), as well as in many posts in this site.