# Is this Proof of (P→Q)→((Q→R)→(P→R)) based on Lukasiewicz Axiom System for CPL Correct?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Given Lukasiewicz axiom system for Classical Propositional Logic (CPL):

(L1)    α→(β→α)

(L2)    (α→(β→γ))→(α→β)→(α→γ)

(L3)    (¬α→¬β)→(β→α)

and the usual Modus Ponens, does my proof of (P→Q)→((Q→R)→(P→R)) below correct? Can someone point out where I made mistake?

(1) (P→R)→((Q→R)→(P→R))     (L1)

(2) (P→(Q→R))→((P→Q)→(P→R)) (L2)

(3) (Q→R)→(P→(Q→R))         (L1)

(4) (P→Q)→(P→R)             (2,3 MP)

(5) (Q→R)→(P→R)             (1,4 MP)

(6) (P→Q)→((Q→R)→(P→R))     (4,5 MP)

Comment: How does your step (4) work?  The only deduction I can see from (2), (3) is the derived rule HS giving $(Q\to R)\to((P\to Q)\to(P\to R))$.

Comment: You can find the proof in the answer to this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1069497/prove-lnot-c-implies-lnot-b-implies-b-implies-c-without-the-deductio) : T2.

Answer (score 2):

No. Steps 4,5, and 6 are all not correct applications of MP